# Convert (numerically ordered) bitmap files to video file using avconv

Tags: linux, image, image-processing, bitmap, avconv

I am attempting to convert a directory full of .bmp files into a .mp4 file (or similar format).

The bitmap files have the following name scheme:

`output_N_1024.bmp`

Where N is an integer in the range 0 to 1023. (No zero padding / fixed width.)

The command I am using is:

`avconv -r 25 -i output_{0..1023}_1024.bmp outputfile.mp4`

This appears to run okay, and takes about a minute to convert all 1024, 1024 by 1024 resolution - (confusing?) bitmap images into a new file, outputfile.mp4.

However, when I attempt to open this file with VLC, a black window briefly flashes up and then closes. VLC then goes back to its mode where it waits for you to tell it which file to open next. No error or warning messages appear from VLC, which seems kind of strange since it seems to be refusing to play.

What can I do to fix this? Perhaps my converting command is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely is that you haven't actually passed the command to encode these files to avconv. This has happened because your shell has expanded the filenames already.

The command i have just managed to get to work on my machine is:

```
avconv -r 2 -i "%d.bmp" -s 600x400 -an out.ogv
```

Also for whatever reason it didn't want to work without explicitely giving it the size, but i don't think this is your problem.

In here quotes tell your shell not to touch this string. %d means digits from 1 to whatever the last file is (if you would want them to be 0-padded this would look like %000d to have maximum of three naughts in front).

VLC has then opened and ran my file just fine.